# Always show a $

Tags: swift, decimal, rounding

SO in swift, I want to make it so that it always shows a $ in a label and some things after that. So far, I have it like this:

```
var billDouble =  NSString(string: userBillTextField.text).doubleValue
tipAmount.text = String( stringInterpolationSegment: billDouble * tax)
```

I want to make it so that in tipAmount it will show something like $9.00 instead of 9.00.

Also, how do I make it so that a double will show up only to a decimal point to the hundreds place? 
So instead of showing 9.089999999 it will round and show 9.09.

Comment: To solve your `$`, you can just append to it like this `"$"+Amount` and to solve your decimal point to hundreds you can see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25232523/2556515)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `NSNumberFormatter` and set the `numberStyle` to `CurrencyStyle`.

```
    let numFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    numFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle

    print(numFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: 9.002310832)))
```

Will output: `Optional("$9.00")` to the console, this just means that it returns an optional (i.e. it *could* return nil). To handle the optional you'd either place a `!` at the end to force unwrap it or do something like `if let` to unwrap it.

Comment: I don't want it to say Optional at the start. How can I remove that?

Comment: Place an exclamation mark at the end of the stringFromNumber function and it will remove the "Optional" message. So change it to `print(numFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: 9.002310832))!)`

Comment: @RishiPanthee Please read about "optionals", it's very important in Swift.